# Failed to post notification channel null log?

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

friends, I am a beginner in android I used some GitHub code in my project my problem is that I am building alarm manager application its notification works perfectly below 8.0 oreo device but the problem is on oreo it notification gives me this exception

Failed to post a notification on channel null

I know I need to create one more channel but don't know how to code for this channel here is my code?

```
package bible.swordof.God.notification;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import bible.swordof.God.MainActivity;
import bible.swordof.God.R;
import bible.swordof.God.Reminder;
import bible.swordof.God.ReminderAdapter;
import bible.swordof.God.ReminderEntity;
import bible.swordof.God.database.ReminderDatabaseHelper;
import bible.swordof.God.database.ReminderDatabaseManager;


public class NotificationService extends Service {

    public final static String KEY = "key";
    public final static String TITLE = "title";
    public final static String REPEAT_INTERVAL = "repeatInterval";
    public final static String REPEAT_INTERVAL_NUMBER = "repeatIntervalNumber";
    public final static String DATE = "date";
    public final static String PRIORITY = "priority";
    public final static String SERVICE = "service";
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 234;



    private Context context;
    private Intent intent;

    private Timer timer;
    private NotificationTimerTask notificationTimerTask;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private Ringtone ringtone;
    private Uri ringtoneUri;

    private Vibrator vibrator;

    private boolean isVibration;
    private boolean isRingtone;

    private String repeatNumberKey, repeatIntervalKey;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        context = getApplicationContext();

        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        timer = new Timer();

        super.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        this.intent = intent;
        sendNotification();

        // The repeatNumber is the number of notification ringtone and (or) vibration repeats the
        // user has set in the app preferences. The default value is -1 (infinite repeats)
        int repeatNumber = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(repeatNumberKey, "-1"));

        if ((isRingtone || isVibration) && repeatNumber != 0) {
            // The repeatInterval is the repeat interval between two subsequent notification signals.
            // The default value is 5 (five seconds).
            int repeatInterval = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(repeatIntervalKey, "5")) * 1000;
            startNotificationTimerTask(repeatNumber, repeatInterval);
        } else if (notificationTimerTask == null) {
            stopSelf();
        }


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    private void startNotificationTimerTask(int repeatNumber, int repeatInterval) {

        if (notificationTimerTask != null) {



            if (ringtone != null) {
                ringtone.stop();
            }

            if (isVibration) {
                vibrator.cancel();
            }

            notificationTimerTask.cancel();


        }


        if (isRingtone) {
            ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
            ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        notificationTimerTask = new NotificationTimerTask(repeatNumber);
        timer.schedule(notificationTimerTask, repeatInterval, repeatInterval);

    }


    private class NotificationTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        long repeatNumber;


        NotificationTimerTask(int repeatNumber) {
            this.repeatNumber = repeatNumber;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (repeatNumber-- != 0) {


                if (isRingtone) {
                    ringtone.play();
                }

                if (isVibration) {
                    vibrator.vibrate(1500);
                }

            } else {
                cancel();
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }


    // This method creates and sends the notification
    private void sendNotification() {

        final long key = intent.getLongExtra(KEY, 0);
        String contentText = intent.getStringExtra(TITLE);
        long date = intent.getLongExtra(DATE, 0L);
        int repeatIntervalNumber = intent.getIntExtra(REPEAT_INTERVAL_NUMBER, 1);
        int priority = intent.getIntExtra(PRIORITY, ReminderEntity.PRIORITY_NORMAL);

        String ringtoneKey, vibrationKey;

        Bitmap largeIcon;


        switch (priority) {

            case ReminderEntity.PRIORITY_NORMAL:
            default:
                ringtoneKey = getString(R.string.pref_normal_priority_ringtone_key);
                vibrationKey = getString(R.string.pref_normal_priority_vibration_key);
                repeatNumberKey = getString(R.string.pref_normal_priority_repeat_number_key);
                repeatIntervalKey = getString(R.string.pref_normal_priority_repeat_interval_key);
                largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_alarm_green_48dp);
                break;

            case ReminderEntity.PRIORITY_HIGH:
                ringtoneKey = getString(R.string.pref_high_priority_ringtone_key);
                vibrationKey = getString(R.string.pref_high_priority_vibration_key);
                repeatNumberKey = getString(R.string.pref_high_priority_repeat_number_key);
                repeatIntervalKey = getString(R.string.pref_high_priority_repeat_interval_key);
                largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_alarm_red_48dp);
                break;

        }


        AlarmHelper.init(context);

        // Create an identifier to make a unique PendingIntent
        Uri identifier = Uri.parse(AlarmHelper.FAKE + String.valueOf(key));

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Reminder.class);

        resultIntent.setData(identifier);
        resultIntent.putExtra(KEY, key);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        deleteIntent.putExtra(SERVICE, true);
        deleteIntent.setData(identifier);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
                deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        NotificationManager notification= (NotificationManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        String uriString = sharedPreferences.getString(ringtoneKey, "content://settings/system/notification_sound");

        isRingtone = !"".equals(uriString);

        ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(uriString);




        builder.setSound(ringtoneUri);
        builder.setContentTitle("PRAYER TIMES");
        builder.setContentText(contentText);
        builder.setTicker(contentText);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_white_48dp);
        builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent);


        int defaultFlags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        isVibration = vibrator.hasVibrator() && sharedPreferences.getBoolean(vibrationKey, true);

        if (!isVibration) {
            builder.setVibrate(null);
        } else {
            defaultFlags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        }

        builder.setDefaults(defaultFlags);


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify((int) key, builder.build());


        setRepeat(date, repeatIntervalNumber, key, contentText, priority);


    }


    // This method sets the next alarm if necessary using the AlarmHelper.
    private void setRepeat(long date, int repeatIntervalNumber,
                           final long key, String title, int priority) {

        ReminderDatabaseHelper.init(context);

        int repeatInterval = ReminderDatabaseManager.getInstance().getRepeatIntervalByKey(key);

        if (repeatInterval != ReminderEntity.NO_REPEATS) {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            switch (repeatInterval) {

                case 5:
                    repeatInterval = Calendar.YEAR;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    repeatInterval = Calendar.MONTH;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    repeatInterval = Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    repeatInterval = Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    repeatInterval = Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;
                    break;

                case 0:
                default:
                    repeatInterval = Calendar.MINUTE;
            }


            calendar.setTimeInMillis(date);
            calendar.add(repeatInterval, repeatIntervalNumber);


            final long nextDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            ReminderDatabaseManager.getInstance().updateDate(key, nextDate);

            AlarmHelper.getInstance().setAlarm(new ReminderEntity(
                    key, title, nextDate,
                    priority, 0, 0, repeatInterval, repeatIntervalNumber
            ));


            final ReminderAdapter reminderAdapter = AlarmHelper.getInstance().getReminderAdapter();

            // If the app is opened set next date using setNextDate method.
            if (reminderAdapter != null) {

                Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        reminderAdapter.setNextDate(key, nextDate);
                    }
                });

            }


        } else {

            ReminderDatabaseManager manager = ReminderDatabaseManager.getInstance();
            manager.updateStatus(key, ReminderEntity.STATUS_INACTIVE);

            final ReminderAdapter reminderAdapter = AlarmHelper.getInstance().getReminderAdapter();

            // If the app is opened deactivate the reminder using deactivateReminder method.
            if (reminderAdapter != null) {

                Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        reminderAdapter.deactivateReminder(key);
                    }
                });

            }


        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {


        if (ringtone != null) {
            ringtone.stop();
        }

        if (isVibration) {
            vibrator.cancel();
        }

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }

        AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001";

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the notification channel first (API 26+) and then pass the channel id to `NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)` (which is null for below 26):

```
// Create the notification channel
String channelId = null;
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (notificationManager != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    channelId = "YOUR_DESIRED_CHANNEL_ID";
    NotificationChannel channel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
    String channelName = "A user-visible name for the channel";
    if (channel == null) {    // if not created yet
        channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        // Setup your channel config as you wish
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        // Create the channel
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
// Setup your notification and notify
```